# Pre-release test for a new package

Tags: ros, bloom-release, pre-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if it is possible to run a pre-release test on a package that's never been released before.
I've been following the [tutorial on ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/PrereleaseTest#Prepare_the_release) up to the point where bloom asks if it should open a pull request to rosdistro, at which moment the tutorial tells you to abort everything.

So the question is, how would the prerelease website know about your package to put it in the [list of repositories available for testing](http://prerelease.ros.org/create_job/indigo), if you don't even have a pull request open. Where does it get the list of repos in general, from the actual `.yaml` file of rosdistro? I'm really confused.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191933/pre-release-test-for-a-new-package/) by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2014-09-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have never release a package before but want to run a prerelease you have to manually create a pull request adding your repository to the rosdistro. Just don't fill in the release version. Then you can select your repo with the version `latest` from the prerelease website.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2014-09-04**:
Not filling in the release version results in an invalid `distribution.yaml`. Which makes me think it wouldn't work that way.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-09-04**:
What makes you think that the file would be invalid without a release version?

**Comment by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on 2014-09-04**:
Travis CI was complaining. But doesn't seem to do it now :)